# Laravel not honoring the routes.php file

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I'm having a strange problem.  I recently moved my Laravel site from one directory to another in my localhost (on a Mac).  Nothing has been right since.  I had to change my .htaccess from the standard Laravel 4 .htaccess to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

which is the alternative Laravel .htaccess for L4.  That at least makes my public folder not be forbidden.  But now Laravel just completely ignores the routes file.  In fact, all routes (those in the file and those not) seem to valid and none seem to call a 404 error, even though I try to call both routes that exist and routes that don't.  I even deleted everything in the routes file except the base route and nothing changed.

How is it possible that routes that don't exist can be called and I don't get the page not found error?  All I get is a white screen.  The same is true except for the base route.  Why is it honoring only the base route (which is '')?  If I change that route to one of the other controllers, it will call that controller.  In short, the only route that works is ''.  Why has everything changed since I moved the site?

Comment: I've even tried changing a lot of the file and folder permissions to 777, thinking it was a permissions issue.

Comment: It's not a permissions issue.  I replaced all of the files I had changed the permissions of with new ones from the download and still the problem persists.  Anyone?

Comment: Does calling index.php/route work? Is the new directory setup to allow .htaccess to override apache directives?

Comment: I tried calling index.php/route and it sometimes works.  Odd huh?  What do I need to do to allow directory to override Apache?

Comment: When I say sometimes, I mean sometimes the data is there, sometimes its just a blank screen.

Comment: What are you using to run a local server, MAMP? If it's MAMP, try restarting the server, sometimes i get errors when changing the path i serve something from.

Comment: It's the PHP on my Mac, not MAMP.

Comment: http://smartwebdeveloper.com/apache/htaccess-problems try number 4 on there. You'll need to find the config file for the mac apache.

Comment: That didn't help.  Anyone else?

Comment: How do you access your site? Do you have a virtual server set up?

Comment: I've tried both through the Mac PHP and MAMP and both have the same issue.

Comment: No virtual host is set up

Comment: I find that a blank white screen is usually a php error.  Have you checked both the server and php error logs?